# zoomable d3 line chart has disappearing data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to add a zoom ability to a historical line chart I've built using a custom data object. I've been using http://codepen.io/brantwills/pen/igsoc/ as a template. The chart is rendered but when I try zooming there are two errors:

Error: Invalid value for path attribute d=""
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (in the last transform, translate of the last part of the zoomed function)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dshamis317/sFp6Q/

This is what my code looks like:

```
function renderHistoricalData(data) {
  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

  data.forEach(function(d) { d.date = parseDate(d.date); });
  // data.sort(function(a,b) { return a.date - b.date; });

  var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
  width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

  var color = d3.scale.category10();

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  // .defined(function(d) { return d.y!=0; })
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.sentiment); });

  var svg = d3.select("#historical_chart").append("svg")
    .call(zoom)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  var sites = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, sentiment: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(sites, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.sentiment; }); }),
    d3.max(sites, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.sentiment; }); })
    ]);

  var site = svg.selectAll(".site")
    .data(sites)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "site");

  site.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  site.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var val = d.values[d.values.length-1];
        return "translate(" + x(val.date) + "," + y(val.sentiment) + ")";
    })
    .attr("x", 3)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "start")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Sentiment (%)");

  function zoomed() {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    svg.selectAll('path.line').attr('d', line);

    sites.selectAll('.site').attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.sentiment) + ")"; }
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, let's walk through each thing.

To start with, in `zoomed`, the last transform doesn't need to be there. In the original, it's there to move the circles, which you don't have.

Also important, your edit on `path.line` sets `d` to the wrong function. If you look at what you're setting `d` to when you first make it, it should be the same, as a general rule of thumb, so it should be `function(d) { return line(d.values); }`, not just `line`.

Now, for the actual reason it's disappearing.

Your scale extent is calculated based off the original domain. However, you don't set the domain until AFTER you call `scaleExtent`, which means your scaling is all based on the default. It's not actually disappearing, it's being compressed to the left hand side of the graph. If you remove your x axis, you'll see the colored smear of all your data flattened against the side.

Move all your domain calculations to above where you build your scale, and it'll be fine.

To make things a bit more concrete:

```
function renderHistoricalData(data) {
  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

  data.forEach(function(d) { d.date = parseDate(d.date); });
  // data.sort(function(a,b) { return a.date - b.date; });

  var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
  width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

  var color = d3.scale.category10();

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  var sites = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, sentiment: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(sites, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.sentiment; }); }),
    d3.max(sites, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.sentiment; }); })
    ]);

  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis")
  // .defined(function(d) { return d.y!=0; })
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.sentiment); });

  var svg = d3.select("#historical_chart").append("svg")
    .call(zoom)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var site = svg.selectAll(".site")
    .data(sites)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "site");

  site.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  site.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var val = d.values[d.values.length-1];
        return "translate(" + x(val.date) + "," + y(val.sentiment) + ")";
    })
    .attr("x", 3)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "start")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Sentiment (%)");

  function zoomed() {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    svg.selectAll('path.line').attr('d', function(d) { return line(d.values); });
  }
}
```

If you want to text to move, you can give it an easily identifiable class, and then update it in `zoomed`.

Giving it a class:

site.append("text")
    .attr("class", "lineLabel")

Updating it in `zoomed`:

```
svg.selectAll(".lineLabel")
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    var val = d.values[d.values.length-1];
    return "translate(" + x(val.date) + "," + y(val.sentiment) + ")";
});
```

This will just make it follow the ends of the lines, but you can modify whatever attributes you like to get the wanted effects.

Comment: that makes perfect sense. thank you! any idea how to make the text zoom with the data? it's currently just sitting idly on the side